# Why is my overlaying div not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, html

So basically to sum it up, I have a flash banner at the top of my website, with an overlaying div that creates the link for it. This was literally the only way that I could get the flash banner to link since it had an embedded actionscript that created an unwanted link.

It works absolutely perfect in Chrome and Firefox, although refuses to work within Internet Explorer.

I am using wordpress, and it is placed within the Header.php file. The piece of shortcode is the flash banner.

```
<div align="center">
<div id="example" align="center" style="width:900px; height:90px; position:absolute; cursor:pointer;" >
</div>
[kml_flashembed movie="http://linktoflashbanner/728x90.swf" height="90" width="728" /]
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("example").onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.domaintolinkto.com.au/"); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Internet Explorer requires a background colour defined for an overlay to catch mouse events over the top of an embedded flash object.

Also, there are better ways to apply your link by using a link tag. Here is a working example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flashWrapper">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="728" height="90">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.flashvortex.com/examples/289.swf?divId=289&amp;autoWidth=0&amp;autoHeight=0" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <embed src="http://www.flashvortex.com/examples/289.swf?divId=289&amp;autoWidth=0&amp;autoHeight=0" width="728" height="90" wmode="opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flashWrapper {
    width:728px;
    height:90px;
    position: relative;
}
.flashWrapper > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8BjxZ/2/)**

Comment: Fantastic answer, works perfectly in all browsers. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: +1 thx @3dgoo  the background trick was eluding me after trying every other trick I could think of

Comment: The way Internet Explorer works is bizarre at times. Glad I could help @charlietfl